# How to automatically increase and release signed apk in Android Studio using Gradle script

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I'm trying to automatically update the versionName and VersionCode parameters in Android Manifest and use them in the output file name instead of "app-release.apk".

From [this site](http://solvedstack.com/questions/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle) I added this code in my build.gradle file:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser

def mVersionCode
def mNextVersionName
def newName

task ('increaseVersionCode') << {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    mVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++mVersionCode + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)

}

task ('incrementVersionName') << {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(4))
    mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion + "." + (buildVersion + 1)
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName=\"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)

}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
        task.dependsOn 'incrementVersionName'
    }
}
```

this code works perfectly, the 2 tasks run and correctly update the manifest file.
Now I want to use the 2 variables `mVersionCode` and `mNextVersionName` in the `release` block inside the `buildTypes` like this:

```
newName = defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + mNextVersionName + " (" + mVersionCode + ").apk"
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each {output ->
                    def file = output.outputFile
                    output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace("app-release.apk", newName))
                }
            }
```

but the returned value of the 2 is null.

I also tried setting properties and extra properties:

```
task.setProperty("vName", mNextVersionName) 
ext.vName = mNextVersionName 
extensions.extraProperties.set("vName", mNextVersionName)
```

in the 2 tasks and getting them in the `release` block without luck.

Does someone has ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: it would be better if we can run that increase code at BuildType { VersionCode..., VersionName...}. yes, I did, do you need the solution of mine?

Comment: Sure, let's see what your solution is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, here is my code of `build.gradle` of application module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply from: 'versionalization.gradle'

def genVersionName = VersionInfo.versionName
def genVersionCode = VersionInfo.versionCode

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vincestyling.exerciseapk"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName genVersionName
        versionCode genVersionCode
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def taskSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
    def assembleTaskName = "assemble${taskSuffix}"

    if (tasks.findByName(assembleTaskName)) {
        def processAPKTask = tasks.create(name: "process${taskSuffix}Apk", type: Copy) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                from output.outputFile
                into output.outputFile.parent

                def newApkName = android.defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + variant.buildType.name + "-" + genVersionName + " (" + genVersionCode + ").apk"
                rename ~/(.+)/, newApkName
            }
        }
        tasks[assembleTaskName].finalizedBy processAPKTask
    }
}
```

the `versionalization.gradle` which applied at head is what I use to increase the **VersionInfo**, then return two values to use.

```
task VersionInfo {
    String FACTOR_KEY = "BUILD_NUMBER_FACTOR"

    File buildDir = file("build")
    buildDir.mkdir()

    File factorPropFile = new File(buildDir, "kbuildfactor.prop")

    Properties props = new Properties()
    if (factorPropFile.exists()) {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(factorPropFile))
    }

    int buildNumberFactor = props.get(FACTOR_KEY) as Integer ?: 0
    buildNumberFactor += 1

    props.put(FACTOR_KEY, buildNumberFactor as String)
    props.store(new FileOutputStream(factorPropFile), null)



    String BASE_VERSION_NAME = "BASE_VERSION_NAME"
    String BASE_VERSION_CODE = "BASE_VERSION_CODE"


    File versionPropFile = file("versioning.properties")
    props.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropFile))


    String baseVersionName = props.get(BASE_VERSION_NAME) as String
    Integer baseVersionCode = props.get(BASE_VERSION_CODE) as Integer

    ext.versionName = baseVersionName + "." + buildNumberFactor
    ext.versionCode = baseVersionCode * 1000 + buildNumberFactor
}
```

it's quite straightforward, read two files to take the necessary fields to constructing the version informations.

we copy/rename the final APK at last.

besides, I achieved the copy/rename part as below first, but it won't work when you have any product flavors, I paste here as another choice.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each {output ->
        def newApkName = android.defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + variant.buildType.name + "-" + genVersionName + " (" + genVersionCode + ").apk"

        def oldApkName = "app-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"

        def file = output.outputFile

        output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(oldApkName, newApkName))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, it's definitely a better solution. I see that your code will increment version Name and code with every configuration (debug, release or custom created one). I'll try it (maybe i'll edit it a bit to suit my needs) and Mark it as solution after that. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, It will increase every time, I'm also still looking for how to prevent it, make it increase only release building, if you found any ideas, please share me.

Answer (score 2):

No one answered, but I found a *working* solution. I don't like it, it can be done in a better way, but for now is the only workaround I found.

I'm still looking for a better solution, if you have one, I'll be happy to read and use it instead of mine.

---

So, I added a new task in the gradle.build file, it just do a copy of the 'app-release.apk' file and rename it using the values in the manifest file:

```
task copia{
    dependsOn('assembleRelease')
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(4))
    def mVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion + "." + (buildVersion)

    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def myVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    copy {
        from 'app-release.apk'
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('app-release.apk', 'com.walker93.catpadova-' + mVersionName + ' (' + myVersionCode + ').apk')
        }
        into 'apk_outputs'
    }
}
```

As you can see it's just a copy and edited version of the code in the 2 previous tasks with a `copy {}` function (here the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html)), it reads the versionName and versionCode values without increment them, then it put them in the new filename i'm going to replace.

This task still requires the 2 other task to be there, so finally you will have 3 tasks.
In the first line of this task there is `dependsOn(assembleRelease)`. This is very important, it will run all the others default release build tasks (included our 2 tasks that increment and write in the manifest) that generate the updated and signed apk.

Now if you try to run the *"generate signed APK..."* you will notice that this task will not run. Instead you will have to manually launch it:

Add your task in the "run configurations" like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fEIn.png) and then you should be able to run the task from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrYd3.png) or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50PEU.png) when you want to publish the signed apk with the custom name. If you want to generate a signed apk with default name (and still increment versionName and versionCode) just use the *"generate signed APK..."* option like before.

Using this method there is no need to add code in the `buildTypes` part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To use extra properties extensions, you need to define them like this:

```
ext {
  mVersionCode = 0
  mNextVersionName = ""
}
```

Then you'll be able access them freely in your buildscript just by using them exactly as you used them in your tasks above.

Comment: I think I already tried this too, I read it in the documentation but it didn't work. I think that the problem is I can't "run" gradle code in the `buildTypes` block.